# GRUB menu alternating between two fonts - where to configure?

Tags: boot, grub2, fonts

The GRUB menu I have, that was created by installing GRUB a few weeks ago on a hard disk from within Ubuntu 17.10, alternates between two fonts, for each second that the timer counts down, and when moving the selection up or down to a different menu option. The menu is perfectly functional, it's just annoying that it redraws the menu in a slightly bigger or smaller font than before every time I press a key.

Where might this behaviour be configured? In my `/etc/default/grub` file, I don't yet have a `GRUB_FONT` line. The only changes I've made to my `/etc/default/grub` file since installing GRUB so far, was to change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` to empty string so that I get to see the boot up debugging messages.

Comment: It's [a bug](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1752767) which is about to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution. GRUB isn't supposed to be able to alternate fonts like this, and the fact that it does it is a bug - but, specifically, removing `--append` from the following line in `/etc/grub.d/00_header`:

```
terminal_output --append ${GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT}
```

... so that it becomes ....

```
terminal_output ${GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT}
```

... and then running:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Worked for me.

[Here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1752767/comments/4) is the Source.